# Initialize collection with data in mongoDB using mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to implement a learning platform where users answer questions and get points. I want in the user profile/collection to hold the questions and the answers as well as the number of tries the users took to get the correct answer.

My mongoose schema is the following:

```
username: { type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true },
hash: String,
salt: String,
realname : String,
score: Number,
CourseFinished: Boolean,
questions: [{
    question : String,
    answer : String,
    noOfTries: Number
}]
```

The route that creates the user is this one:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

  var user = new User();

  user.username = req.body.username;

  user.setPassword(req.body.password);

  user.questions.question = "What is the language used to write websites?"; //this one doesn't work
  user.questions.answer.push("HTML"); //this one doesn't work either


    user.save(function (err){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()})
  });
});
```

How can I initialize an array of questions and answers with the creation of the user?

Comment: Looks like `user.questions` is an array. So you should create a question object `var q = { question: 'my question', answer: 'my answer', noOfTries: 1 }` and push that into user questions instead. `user.questions.push(q);`

Comment: You are correct, make it an answer. Any idea on how to initialize the collection? Or should I make 50 different objects and push them into the array at /register is OK?

Comment: I would say creating all the questions and saving it on registration is fine if that's what your business logic requires. If all the questions are the same for each user, you could probably store all the questions in a separate collection and instead have an `user.answers` array instead of `user.questions` that references each of those questions by ID, to avoid re-creating the questions for each user. I haven't used mongodb/mongoose before so if there's a better way maybe someone else can provide the answer for that :)